# Unexpected behaviour while using ostringstream

Tags: c++

Getting different output in following cases

```
std::string temp, temp1 = "foo", temp2 = "bar";
    std::vector<char> test;
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << temp1;
    temp = s.str();
    std::copy(s.str().begin(), s.str().end(), std::back_inserter(test));
    std::copy(temp2.begin(), temp2.end(), std::back_inserter(test));
    std::cout << &test[0];
```

Output : foo

```
 std::string temp, temp1 = "foo", temp2 = "bar";
    std::vector<char> test;
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << temp1;
    temp = s.str();
    std::copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), std::back_inserter(test));
    std::copy(temp2.begin(), temp2.end(), std::back_inserter(test));
    std::cout << &test[0];
```

Output : foobar     can somebody explain why this happened

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The streams [`str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str) function returns the string *by value*.

That means the two `s.str()` calls will return *two different strings*, and their respective `begin` and `end` iterators will be for different strings, making the `std::copy` call invalid and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: so when str() function is called each time it creates a string object in memory and then return the iterator

Comment: @ArjunUS Yes that's correct. And iterators must come from the very same string object to be "compatible".